# How to mark links, handled with javascript as visited?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, hyperlink, visited

I have a navigation like this:

```
<div id="melement1" class="mlink" data-slink="kultur">
    <a href="#kultur">Kultur|Bildung</a>
</div>
```

This works fine, and with this link, I open another subnavigation:

```
case "kultur": 
    document.getElementById('navi_kultur').style.visibility = 'visible';
    break;
```

The subnavigation looks like this:

```
<div id="kultur1" class="link" data-subsite="kultur/hoehenrausch">
    <a href="#kultur?hoehenrausch">Linz 09 - Höhenrausch, Linz</a>
</div>
```

and I handle it via Ajax:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var subsite = $(this).data('subsite');
    $('#showProject').load('php/subsite.php?page='+subsite);
```

So my question is:

How can I set the state of the links of my subnavigation to active/visited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `visited` class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a { color: red; }
    a.visited { color: blue; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".link a").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("visited");
    });
</script>
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xzRZ/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Have you defined the `visited` style in your stylesheet? I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: a:visited {
 color: #669900;
 text-decoration:none;
}

I defined it in my css. Should work too?

Comment: Also, you need to drill down to the actual link. Your code is styling the containing div, not the link itself. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to add another class from my css file and yours, both not working, there isn't changing anything in my div or link. It stays the same all the time.

Comment: Again, you need to drill down to the actual link, i.e. `$(".link a")`. Your code is just styling the containing div.

Comment: I have more than one link of class "link".
Is $(this) referring to every div with this class or just the one i clicked? Do I have to refer it with my subsite variable?

Comment: `$(".link a")` will refer only to the link that is clicked.

Comment: I included a link to a jsFiddle in my answer.